# Create a new dataframe out of dozens of df.sum() series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have several pandas DataFrames of the same format, with five columns.

I would like to sum the values of each one of these dataframes using `df.sum()`. This will create a Series for each Dataframe, still with 5 columns.

My problem is how to take these Series, and create another Dataframe, one column being the filename, the other columns being the five columns above from `df.sum()`

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

batch_of_dataframes =  glob.glob("*.txt")

newdf = []
for filename in batch_of_dataframes:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df['filename'] = str(filename)
    df = df.sum()
    newdf.append(df)

newdf = pd.concat(newdf, ignore_index=True)
```

This approach doesn't work unfortunately. 'df['filename'] = str(filename)' throws a TypeError, and the creating a new dataframe `newdf` doesn't parse correctly.

How would one do this correctly?

How do you take a number of `pandas.Series` objects and create a `DataFrame`?

Comment: Can you post some example data mocking one of your input dataframes?  There are a few issues here.  

1.  df.sum() returns a series with `len(df.columns)` rows (or `len(df)` depending on whether axis=0 or 1).  There are no columns in a series. 
2.  new_df is just a list of series, so you'll ultimately end up with just another series.
3.  You should post the full traceback on `df['colname'] = 'value'`.  This really shouldn't be failing.  It makes me think that for whatever reason, your data is just actually 1 column and being read in as a series, but posting some example data will clarify this.

Comment: I believe `glob.glob('.txt')` is returning an empty list.  I believe you want `glob.glob('*.txt')`

Comment: @Alexander Sorry, typo

Comment: @ThomasTu How do I go from a list of Series with 'Filename' as a column to a dataframe? I think that's the problem---I don't understand this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in this order:

1. Create an empty list, say `list_of_series`.
2. For every file:

   1. load into a data frame, then save the sum in a series `s`
   2. add an element to s: `s['filename'] = your_filename`
   3. append `s` to `list_of_series`
3. Finally, concatenate (and transpose if needed):

   ```
   final_df = pd.concat(list_of_series, axis = 1).T
   ```

### Code

Preparation:

```
l_df = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,5), columns = list("ABCDE")) for _ in range(5)]
for i, df in enumerate(l_df):
    df.to_csv(str(i)+'.txt', index = False)
```

Files *.txt are comma separated and contain headers.

```
! cat 1.txt
A,B,C,D,E
0.18021800981245173,0.29919271590063656,0.09527248614484807,0.9672038093199938,0.07655003742768962
0.35422759068109766,0.04184770882952815,0.682902924462214,0.9400817219440063,0.8825581077493059
0.3762875793116358,0.4745731412494566,0.6545473610147845,0.7479829630649761,0.15641907539706779
```

And, indeed, the rest is quite similar to what you did (I append file names to a series, not to data frames. Otherwise they got concatenated several times by `sum()`):

```
files = glob.glob('*.txt')
print(files)
['3.txt', '0.txt', '4.txt', '2.txt', '1.txt']

list_of_series = []
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    s = df.sum()
    s['filename'] = f
    list_of_series.append(s)
final_df = pd.concat(list_of_series, axis = 1).T

print(final_df)
          A         B          C        D        E filename
0    1.0675   2.20957    1.65058  1.80515  2.22058    3.txt
1  0.642805   1.36248  0.0237625  1.87767  1.63317    0.txt
2   1.68678   1.26363   0.835245  2.05305  1.01829    4.txt
3   1.22748   2.09256   0.785089  1.87852  2.05043    2.txt
4  0.910733  0.815614    1.43272  2.65527  1.11553    1.txt
```

Comment: Could you offer code? I believe this is roughly what I have above

Comment: @ShanZhengYang Here you are. I may only speculate that your `pd.read_csv` went wrong: differently formatted files? or glob accidently matched unwanted files? If not that, I would try to run the three lines from within the loop on a single file first.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this specific question :

> @ThomasTu How do I go from a list of Series with 'Filename' as a
>   column to a dataframe? I think that's the problem---I don't understand
>   this

It's essentially what you have now, but instead of appending to an empty list, you append to an empty dataframe.   I think there's an inplace keyword if you don't want to reassign newdf on each iteration.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

batch_of_dataframes =  glob.glob("*.txt")

newdf = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in batch_of_dataframes:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df['filename'] = str(filename)
    df = df.sum()
    newdf = newdf.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```